# ConnectionException in Camel when trying to conenction to local SMTP server

Tags: java, email, apache-camel, connectionexception

I have a local SMTP server, implemented in the Python core scripts, which simply prints the body of the email received :

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:3333. (on Windows)
```

When I telnet localhost 3333, the connection succeeds and I can send an email using SMTP.

However, when I build (via Java DSL) a route with an endpoint producer to this same address, the connection fails and sends an exception

```
.to("smtp://localhost:3333");
```

Part of the exception is :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 3333;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.DefaultJavaMailSender.send(DefaultJavaMailSender.java:111)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailProducer.process(MailProducer.java:56)
```

Any idea on what is going on ? The process hosting the CamelContext is on the same machine as the telnet client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check will it work if you will use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost"?

Comment: Yes I tried with a direct IP address, the result was the same.

Comment: Maybe port blocked by firewall? Also can you check some other port like 10000?

Comment: I tried to bind address 127.0.0.1 and it worked ! Binding 127.0.0.1 in SMTP and connecting to localhost in Camel works fine.
My bad, I didn't understand your comment !